# mongodb update item in an object isnt working as expected

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using python with mongodb in the backend.
my data looks like that:

```
data = {"_id": ObjectId("anything", "x": {"one": "number", "two": "number"})}
```

I am trying to update all values in x that meet a certain condition.
Here is what i am trying:

```
col.update( {"x.one": "number"}, {"$set": {"x.onnneeee": "number"}}, multi=True)
col.update_many( {"x.one": "number"}, {"$set": {"x.onnneeee": "number"}})
```

However, After checking the database. I see the new value is being added to the end of the "x" object while the object `{"x.one": "number"}` isnt being changed. any explanation why this is happening ?

Comment: Question 1. Which version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $unset in the same update dict to unset x.one

```
col.update( {"x.one": "number"}, {"$set": {"x.onnneeee": "number"}, "$unset": {"x.one": ""}}, multi=True)
```

The first arg  `{"x.one": "number"}` is just a filter query and identifies records which are to be updated. The 2nd arg sets what updates to perform on the selected records

Comment: this has solved it but I still dont understand why update doesnt do that on its own. Thanks\